# Delete button refreshes the page if only 1 admin exists without displaying the dialog. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, session

Following is my code. I want to delete the admin if more than 1 admins exists and alert works in this case perfectly. But when I want to delete the admin while the admin is the sole admin, I want the page to alert saying "Only 1 admin exists. Can't delete". But instead, the code doesn't display ay alert and just refreshes the page. What am I missing in the code?

```
<div style="width: 60%;" class="jumbotron">
          <form action="deleteAdmin.php" method = "post">
            <p class="h5">Are you sure you want to delete your account?</p>
            <input name="deleteMe" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete"
            id = "login">
            <a href="Settings.php" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
          </form>
          <?php
                if(isset($_POST['deleteMe']))
                {
                    $username = $_SESSION['username1'];
                    $query = 'select * from admins';
                    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>1)
                    {
                        $query = "delete from admins where email='$username'";
                        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        session_destroy();
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Admin Deleted Successfully!!!");
                              document.location.href="../adminLogin.php";</script>';
                    }
                    else {
                      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("You are the only admin...
                                Cannot remove the sole admin of a database..");
                            document.location.href="Settings.php";</script>';
                    }
                }
          ?></div>
```

Comment: You cant have new lines in javascript strings, also from a UI aspect its better to do the lookup first and tell the user and disable the button, instead of using ugly alerts.

Comment: Your `if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>1)` needs to be changed to `if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>=1)` seeing your *I want the page to alert saying "Only 1 admin exists. Can't delete"*. If one exists, your conditional statement will fail on `>1`. You can also do `>0` to check if there is at least one, but that may not be the best solution here.

Comment: Wow. What a dumb mistake by me. You saved my day. I could never have noticed that. Thanks @LawrenceCherone .

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner doing so would also delete the sole admin.

Comment: This is also open to sql injection. Ever heard of prepared statements? You should.

Comment: Yea. This is just a basic version which has almost a million security flaws. It is just a mini-project so didn't pay much attention at that end. Thanks for reminding me of that attack anyway.

Comment: I'd check for both in separate conditional statements. It's a bit tricky but can be done. I'd use a relational table instead and have a boolean flag on admin only, rather than assigning multiple admins to different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your alert text have line breaks? I believe that is the reason.

If you want the alert to have two lines, use \ n after the first string.